# Very weird issue with characters and undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

OK, check this one :

- Visit this page here: http://efluo.net/
- Open the JavaScript console

**TEST 1:**

Copy-paste this (and press enter) : `window.DB["ar,i>í"]`

It will show something like this :

```
Object {rootChange: "í", subjuntivo: Array[4], rootFind: "i", gerundio: "$ando", indicativo: Array[5]…}
```

**TEST 2:**

Now, copy-paste *this* one (It looks the exact same thing, well wait!) : `window.DB["ar,i>í"]`

And the response is :

```
undefined
```

---

OK, so could you please explain to me what's going on and how it is to be resolved (convert the second one, to the first one)?

Comment: @DesertIvy A custom object initialiased at start-up

Comment: Why would you use such a property name to begin with ?

Comment: Because they are not the same: `"í" === "í"`, those are different characters.

Comment: This question is too localized.

Comment: It is working fine with firefox

Comment: `"í".localeCompare("í")` (both being different characters) returns `0`, just as a random piece of trivia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing weird about it, they're different characters that look the same. If you convert them to hex:

í = `69 cc 81`
í = `c3 ad`

So, just replace one of them with the other.
Why would you be using characters like that in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

That's because the length of the first string is 7, not 6. That last "character" of the first string is actually two characters that look like one. Try this:

```
var a = "ar,i>í", b = "ar,i>í";
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  console.log(a[i]);
}
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
  console.log(b[i]);
}
```

Comment: OMG. OK, that's quite a surprise. Is there any realistic way that string is converted the version with the smaller number of characters?

Comment: If you mean with any other simillar character, then probably no. But this exact case can be solved like this: `str.replace(/í/g, "í")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the ASCII character encoding for both:

The first is:

```
[119, 105, 110, 100, 111, 119, 46, 68, 66, 91, 34, 97, 114, 44, 105, 62, 105, 769, 34, 93]
```

The second is:

```
[119, 105, 110, 100, 111, 119, 46, 68, 66, 91, 34, 97, 114, 44, 105, 62, 237, 34, 93]
```

So the second example is missing the part of the unicode character that corresponds to `769`.

Check yourself using the code I used:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0, l = s.length; i < l; i++) {
  arr.push(s.charCodeAt(i));
}

console.log(arr);
```